# Enter Email and password Login using Google+ in an app in iphone

Tags: iphone, authentication, gmail, google-plus

I want to enter Email and password then login from google account in an app. I have used Google+ SDK but it will redirect to Gmail site but i dont want this but i want User have to enter Email and Password for Gmail with in an app and press Login button.

Is there any source code OR suggestion please post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user should not enter their Google email/password into your application for security reasons.

The sign-in button provided by the [Google+ iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios) allows the user to use their Google+ identity in your app. The button also manages the OAuth 2.0 flow and token lifecycle.